# Cannot create an item of this type in this folder Outlook

Tags: forms, outlook, subdirectory

I want to assign a form to my subfolder but having the prompt from outlook 
"You cannot create an item of this type in this folder". I know about selection the default form while going into properties of folder and select the form but its working and I am getting this error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW9fg.jpg)

Comment: What is the default folder class and what message class are you passing to Items.Add?

Comment: When ever I try to assign some subfolder to a form its promp this “Cannot create an item of this type in this folder“

Comment: Assign now? What is the relevant snippet of your code?

Comment: I am not using any code snippet. I am just creating a new folder under inbox and then right click on that subfolder and try to assign built in form from properties and getting the error

Comment: What is the exact form message class? What is the folder type?

Comment: Default folder type and prompt is comming “Cannot create an iterm of this type in this folder"

Comment: Again, what is the exact form message class?

Comment: Whats does you mean by exact form message class?

Comment: When you design your form, you specify the message class. What is it?

Comment: Well currently I am only try to using the built in form provided by outlook.

Comment: And what form is that?

Comment: Same issue on selecting any form like Appointment, Contact etc

Comment: Well, it is a mail folder, of course Outlook won't let you use Appointment or Contact form.